# Issue when editing/deleting Datatable is applied using Ajax

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

I'm facing a problem with deleting and editing a row data. My code is working correctly but when the data-tables are applied on it then the delete after 10 number doesn't work even if I want to check it by `console.log()` or `alert` they don't show any action there by clicking on delete or edit.

It's working correctly when Datatable is not applied

```
 <tbody>

            <?php
            $count=1;
            foreach ($users as $row) {
            ?>

            <tr>
              <td><?=$count;?></td>
              <td><?=$row->name;?></td>
              <td><?=$row->fname;?></td>
              <td><?=$row->reg_no;?></td>
              <td><?=$row->email;?></td>
              <td><?=$row->address;?></td>
              <td><?=$row->contact;?></td>
              <td><?=$row->gender;?></td>
              <td><?=$row->nationality;?></td>
              <td><?=$row->admission_date;?></td>
              <td><img src="<?=base_url()?>assets/images/students/<?=$row->image?>" width="50px" height="50px"></td>

              <td><a class="Edit" EditID="<?=$row->id;?>" ><i class="fa fa-fw fa-edit"></i></a> |
                  <a class="AdminDelete" data="<?=$row->id;?>" ><i class="fa fa-fw fa-trash-o"></i></a>


              </td>
            </tr>
          <?php $count++;} ?>
            </tbody>
```

> Ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".AdminDelete").click(function(){
        var id=$(this).attr("data");
        alert(id);
        exit();
        $.ajax({
        url:"'.base_url().'Admin/customer",
        data:{deleteid:id},
        method:"post",
        success:function(data)
        {
           alert("Record deleted successfully");
        }
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: make sure that in your  `url:"'.base_url().'admin/customer",` controller name is in lower case.

Comment: does the alert shows up with a blank item or does it not showing alert at all?

Comment: make it  `$("body").on("click", ".AdminDelete", function() {  var id=$(this).attr("data");
    alert(id); }`.

Comment: change the url like this  url: "<?php echo base_url();?>Admin/customer",

Comment: you wrote return function in controller or not while return anything from controller i will shows alert box

Comment: yes sir i write the return

Comment: in my code it working well but when the data-tables is apply then i don't working. then if i show the id in alert it dont work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update you jquery click function with below :-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

$(document).on("click", '.AdminDelete', function(e)
    var id=$(this).attr("data");
    alert(id);
    $.ajax({
    url:"'.base_url().'Admin/customer",
    data:{deleteid:id},
    method:"post",
    success:function(data)
    {
       alert("Record deleted successfully");
    }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: @jamilshah then please feel free to accept my answer if its useful for you.

Comment: yes got it. and you forget the { after the function(e). like you need to write it. function(e){